# Django rest_framework serializer ignoring POST data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer:

```
class InterestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.RelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Importance
        fields = ('id', 'category', 'is_important')
```

for the model:

```
class Importance(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey("Profile")
    category = models.ForeignKey(InterestCategory)
    is_important = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('profile', 'category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category.name
```

I have a simple POST via ajax to update the model. I can confirm the data posted is correct:

```
POST:
csrfmiddlewaretoken = u'ts0PEgLZIqkeOXp2a7z8Ex5eSbvGFOi3'
is_important = u'False'
id = u'2'
```

However, if I check the data in the serialize, it's different:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = InterestSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print serializer.data
```

In terminal

```
{'id': None, 'category': None, 'is_important': False}
```

Why isn't the id (pk) being loaded into the serialize data?

edit:

```
      <form id="{{ interest.pk }}">{% csrf_token %}
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='{{ interest.pk }}'>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="is_important" value="True"> Use 
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="is_important" value="False"> Don't Use 
        </label>
      </form>

<script>
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    $.post("/api/categories", ($(this).closest("form").serialize()));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: are you posting with jquery?  Can you post that code?  DRF is likely expecting JSON encoded data and you might be submitting form-data

Comment: How are the parsers configured for DRF? You seem to try to POST form-encoded data, did you set the content-type header accordingly and is the `FormParser` in the list of parsers? (see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers)

Comment: Setting the parser did not seem to have an effect

Answer (score 0):

Django will ignore your `id` argument. The `id` field is an auto-increment primary key and it is only available after you save the object. Your code should change like this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    serializer = InterestSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        print serializer.data
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But, this was actually updating an existing instance. the `print serializer.data` was just my way of showing that the Pk was not being saved. Attempting to save throws a 500 error

Answer (score 0):

I know it has a couple of years, but I'll answer anyway.

To update, you actually have to do this:

```
InterestSerializer(instance=<instance to update>, data=<data dict>)
```

Important to say that there's no need for setting the `id` in the request body.

And about the 500 status code, you'd have to show us more details, like the message shown, traceback etc.